# JSF 1.2 : Redirecting to a different portlet from phaselistener

Tags: jsf-1.2

Am using JSF 1.2

In phaselistener of one portlet, if some condition matches, I want to redirect to a different portlet altogether. I have the below code in beforePhase method

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.redirect("/my-other-portlet-url");
```

Its not working. Even I tried putting it in afterPhase method. Didnt work.

What is the right way to do this? Can redirection be done to another portlet in my scenario?

Regards,

Vikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();     
NavigationHandler handler = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
handler.handleNavigation(context, null, "my-other-portlet-url"); //put there name of your page
```

This should work even from `PhaseListener`

Comment: You should put there as a parameter name of the view, not the page itself. For example if you have `home/index.xhtml`, parameter should be `home/index`